# Update records of database table : Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, edit

I need to update the database table according to the edited data.

**controller**

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $subscriptionplan = SubscriptionPlan::find($request->id);
    $subscriptionplan->update($request->all());        
    return back();        
}
```

But nothing happens when I submit the form. When I use `dd($request->all());` at the beginning of the function, it correctly shows the edited data as follows.

```
array:10 [▼
  "_method" => "patch"
  "_token" => "gOCL4dK6TfIgs75wV87RdHpFZkD7rBpaJBxJbLHF"
  "editname" => "SUP_EVA_001"
  "editdesc" => "des"
  "editprice" => "1000.050"
  "editlimit" => "1"
  "editperunit" => "20.000"
  "editexceedunit" => "30.000"
  "productid" => "1"
  "id" => "1"
]
```

But database has not been updated.

My table name is `Table: subscription_plans` and model is `SubscriptionPlan`

These are the table columns:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
        'price',
        'usage_limit',
        'charge_per_unit',
        'charge_per_unit_exceed',
        'is_limit_exceed_considered',
        'product_id'
    ];
```

Any idea on how to solve it or what I have done wrong?

Comment: Are any errors being pushed to you `storage/log/laravel.log` file?

Comment: There is no such file like that in my project

Comment: Are you sure, laravel logs errors there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for Laravel to automatically fill the model attributes, the indexes of the array passed to the fill method must correspond to your model attributes names.

Also, instead of

```
$subscriptionplan->update($request->all());
```

Use

```
$subscriptionplan->fill($request->all());
```

Then save the subscription plan with `$subscriptionplan->save();`

Comment: Still database is not updating.

Comment: The attributes may be guarded, add attributes that need to change into a fillable array attributes. (doc about this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Comment: the model use "protected $fillable" method

Comment: The array indexes in $request->all() array should be the same as the model attributes. editname should be name, and so on

Comment: I think I have got it wrong there. I updated my question with the table columns.

Comment: As I said, the request attributes must have the same name as your model attributes when you pass the array to the fill method. Otherwise, laravel can't infer which array element corresponds to which attribute

Comment: Thank you. I changed the name of my attributes and now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If your solution did not work, try the 1by1 like this.

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $subscriptionplan = SubscriptionPlan::find($request->id);
    $subscriptionplan->_method = $request->_method;
    $subscriptionplan->_token = $request->_token;
    $subscriptionplan->editname = $request->editname;
    $subscriptionplan->editdesc = $request->editdesc;
    $subscriptionplan->editprice = $request->editprice;
    $subscriptionplan->editlimit = $request->editlimit;
    $subscriptionplan->editperunit = $request->editperunit;
    $subscriptionplan->editexceedunit = $request->editexceedunit;
    $subscriptionplan->productid = $request->productid;
    $subscriptionplan->save();        
    return back();        
}
```